# How to acccess Data in Azure-datapool from GCP

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I receive a daily data in Datapool and these are limited to access with SFTP, SCP. I want to process the data from GCP. I've tried to setup a Compute Engine to get access to the Data, but that doesn't work!
Normally,I've to access these through WinSCP and I used PuTTY to setup Jupyter Notebook and process these Data.
But how to do that in GCP as well? I want to write a script to process the daily data.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide more detail in which way did you try to copy files from Azure data pool via Compute Engine VM.

Comment: I tried to transform the Data from az disk to Storage Blob and then using CE from az storage Blob  to GCS afterthat to Bigquery usign BigQuery transfer service.

Comment: I posted possible solution in my answer. Please check and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access data from Azure data pool from GCP BigQuery by following steps below:

1. [create](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) Linux VM instance (you can try to do it with [free tire](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free) VM)
2. [create](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) Google Storage bucket
3. [mount](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#using) your bucket to VM instance with [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse)
4. copy data from Azure data pool to mounted bucket at GCP VM instance via `scp`
5. [query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage)  data from Google Storage bucket

To do on schedule you can create some simple bash script that just run `scp` command and use [Cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to run it.

Comment: The Step Nr. 4 is for me  the most challenging Part .Normally, I have used WinSCP  on my Local to access the Data . it's not easy to transfer the Data directly here. Thanks!